# Put text in begin each line and end line in excel

Tags: excel

Looking for add text in each begin line and the end of line,
attached screen shot which explain better the result which need.
the closer which i get to result is by using SUBSTITUTE formula, but need to fix it little bit.
here is the formula:

```
="<p>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10),"</p>"&CHAR(10),1),CHAR(10),CHAR(10)&"<p>",1)&"</p>"
```

Thank's for help!

[image: Excel Screen Shot]

Comment: `="<p>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10),"</p>"&CHAR(10)&"<p>")&"</p>"`

Comment: Quick and accurate answer, Thank's Scott!